# "Return" suddenly makes 1,5 lines instead of one (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

I have a strange problem, since yesterday pressing "Return" results in 1.5 lines instead of 1. This affects several applications including Thunderbird and Openoffice-Writer, while other applications, such as notepad++ are not affected.

This is truly weird, because I definitely didn't change anything in these applications, but I don't know of anything that could cause this system wide. Any ideas?

Thanks.
EDIT: To be more precise, 1,5 lines means like the margin between paragraphs. But neither Thunderbird, Writer, nor other applications should make paragraphs on enter, at least I'm not used to that they do..

Comment: Maybe add a bounty? It will bring in more people to answer it.

Comment: be warned though, bounty won't guarantee an answer. But still worth a shot.

Comment: Are you sure you aren’t just confused by the difference of plain text vs formatted text (where paragraphs exist, which is what Enter produces)? Because that’s normal behavior.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what is "1.5 lines" ? Do you mean inter-paragraph spacing?

Comment: Some screenshots would be helpful here.

Comment: If you boot into safe mode does this behavior exhbit itself?

Comment: Have you got some paragraph padding applied to the text styles? NP++ is a plain text  editor so wouldn't be affected by styling changes like the other 2.

Comment: Shift+Enter should be only next line.. if that is the case, search for paragraph options in the software affected.. it's more likely to be setting in the software editor and not a Win10 global thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Thunderbird, it's a new feature with the most recent update 45.0.

You can turn it off in Options > Composition > General. The feature is called "When using paragraph format, the enter key creates a new paragraph" and it defaults to on [X].

I don't know about the change to OpenOffice. Maybe a recent update to that, too?

Answer (score 2):

I will list some simple steps.

1. If you have set the Windows font display size to 125% or 150% this might happen. Try resetting it to the default. The path for the control panel applet is 'Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display'
2. If you press Ctrl+5 key, Openoffice does this. Try clicking the combination again and see if it works.

Comment: your answer would have deserved the bounty, too, but sadly I had to choose one. I chose raima's answer, cause it addressed the "black magic", that the issue suddenly appeared without me changing a thing. Still, your answer solved the "Writer" issue. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear it.